# OpenGL - glDrawArray & VBO cause crashed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I found that we could not use VBO and Draw Array at the same time... it's cause crash....
I created a small project to test it, you can download it here:

http://www.mediafire.com/?8jnqip7ca97u6vi

it's a simple project init with OpenGL 1.1 (Creating a template Open GL in XCode and include some VBO sample code from : http://sdickinson.com/wordpress/?p=122).

Here my Draw Code:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (!build) [self BuildVBO];
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
    if (build) [self DrawVBO];

    glTranslatef(0.0f, (GLfloat)(sinf(transY)/2.0f), 0.0f);
    transY += 0.075f;

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, squareColors);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

if you uncomment the glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); App will be crashed.

I dont know why, anyone here have the experience in use glDrawArray and VBO at the same time ?